# In Xcode 9 unable to validate ipa file while archive in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

When I am trying to validate IPA file, unable to archive file in Xcode 9.

Generally when we validate the iPa file, it should ask development team to use for provisioning like below image. but for me not asking anything and showing that screen 1.[image]

Comment: There isn't much information here. What exactly happens when you click on Validate and follow the prompts? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: What is the error you are getting... where are you stuck